# Issue parsing dateTime from one website

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-parsing

I am parsing datetime form a website to get day of the week, mont, year, time, using 
these 3 methods which are working fine with all the other sites I have tested but not with this [one](http://www.railwaygazette.com/rss.xml),  which of course is the one I need to use.

```
protected string GetDayOfWeek(string dateTimeString)
{
    DateTime result = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString);
    string dayOfWeek = Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), result.DayOfWeek);

    return dayOfWeek;
}

protected string GetTimeOnly(string dateValue)
{
    return System.DateTime.Parse(dateValue).ToString("hh:mm");
}

protected string GetDateOnly(string dateValue)
{
    return System.DateTime.Parse(dateValue).ToString("ddd, MMM d, yyyy");
}
```

it keeps giving me this error:

> System.FormatException not managed by the user code.
>   HResult=-2146233033   Message=String not recognised as valid DateTime

I have spent quite some time trying to sort out this problem without success. It was working fine until yesterday. If I visit the website or I check those feeds in a reader, the date time is there and even if I check the variable the time is there.

[image]

What am I missing? Any hint?

**Update**
I have even tried to mashup several sites with yahoo pipes and it is working but as soon as I add the above mentioned site it gives me error. Obviously the problem is generated by something in the feeder website but I cannot find the reason.

Comment: do you know the format of `dateTimeString`? is it in this format -> `Sat, 01 Mar 2014 06:00:00 +0100`

Comment: do you mean the format used on the website?

Comment: no no , im asking about your datestring. is it in `Sat, 01 Mar 2014 06:00:00 +0100` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becuase your string does not have a standart date/time format. That's why your [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will fail.

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string dateTimeString = "Sat, 01 Mar 2014 06:00:00 +0100";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString,
                               "ddd',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss K",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
3/1/2014 5:00:00 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/DrwczO)</kbd>.

For more information, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Soner, thanks but what I do not understand what is changed overnight. The situation is a bit more complex. I need to extract separately the components of the data as per my question. To reuse the parts in graphics.

Comment: @FeliceM _Well_, I can't know what changed overnight. `:)` But if you want to know how to parse this string to datetime, that's the way.

Comment: Thank you Soner. Actually just came in my mind that the methods in my question are from a Telerik demo.